Decrement a field in a subdocument of an array field or add it if it not exist in MongoDB
I have a MongoDb collection of documents structured like the following:
{
  _id: "9f854842-7475-4714-1234-7ac72beef0d9",
  name: "SalesDemo",
  monthlyQuotas: 43,
  userUsages: [
    {
      userId: "user1",
      dailyQuotas: 6
    }
  ],
}

Given a operatorId and a userId, what i wan to achieve is decrement monthlyQuotas by 1 of the document with _id = operatorId and:

Decrement the field dailyQuotas of a subdocument with userId = userId by 1 in the array userUsages of the same document if it exists
Or, if it not exist, create a document in the array userUsages with userId=userId and dailyQuotas=9

What it is very important is that this operation must be atomic because several concurrent requests can be done for both the operator and user.
Is it possible to accomplish this maybe with a findOneAndUpdate or Aggregation pipeline? It's important that the operation returns the new updated document because i have to verify the quota values.

something like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/sma5vrCiOaK

It seems interesting but the method update is deprecated and i need the single document as a response (the new one or the old if present, its not important). Is it possible using something like the method findOneAndUpdate?

can you try with this pipeline  on findOneAndUpdate

Thanks to @cmgchess comment, the following query deals with my requirements:
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: "9f854842-7475-4714-1234-7ac72beef0d9",
  },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        monthlyQuotas: {
          $subtract: ["$monthlyQuotas", 1],
        },
        userUsages: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $in: ["user2", "$userUsages.userId"],
            },
            {
              $map: {
                input: "$userUsages",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: ["$$this.userId", "user2"],
                    },
                    {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          dailyQuotas: {
                            $subtract: ["$$this.dailyQuotas", 1],
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    "$$this",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$userUsages",
                [
                  {
                    userId: "user2",
                    dailyQuotas: 9,
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  {
    returnNewDocument: true,
  }
);

